# The method setOnLongClickListener(View.OnLongClickListener) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (new OnLongClickListener(){})

Tags: android, imageview, syntax-error, long-press

I have an ImageView that I want to respond to a long-press.

I have implemented this very method in another application without any issues but I just copied and pasted the code into another application and it's giving me the following syntax error:

```
The method setOnLongClickListener(View.OnLongClickListener) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (new OnLongClickListener(){})
```

The code block is:

```
imageView.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
    public boolean onLongClick(View arg0) {
        // do something here
        return true;                         
    }
});
```

This view method is available since API level 1 so I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Try to put log inside onLongClick function. method onLongClick is execute?

Comment: It's a syntax error, not a run-time error.

Comment: if syntax  - set full path to onLongClickListener interface. Such a `android.View.OnLongClickListener`

Comment: @Mikel  Yeah.  Just added `import android.view.View.OnLongClickListener;` and all is good.  Move your comment to answer and I can accept.  Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome!,Catch It!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check your imports, make sure you are importing the correct OnLongClickListener.

Answer (score 1):

Two imports are needed

```
import android.view.View.OnLongClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change a `OnLongClickListener`  to full path to `android.View.OnLongClickListener`

```
 imageView.setOnLongClickListener(new android.View.OnLongClickListener() {
        public boolean onLongClick(View arg0) {
            // do something here
            return true;                         
        }
    });
```